How to Get File Type passed into multipart form-data with Multer When Uploading to S3 in Node.js?
I'm using Multer to handle file uploads in my Node.js application, and I'm uploading files to an S3 bucket. I need to get the type I pass into multi-part formdata before uploading. How can I achieve this?
As I have mentioned in below Image like I want type invoice value before uploading file into S3 and and before going into multer upload function.

router.post('/upload', 
    passportAuth.authenticateJwt, 
    authorization.isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            upload.array('files', 10)(req, res, (err:any) => {
                if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                    const customError = new Error("Size limit exceed");
                    return res.status(400).json({ status: "error", message: customError.message });
                } else if (err) {
                    const customError = new Error("Allow files only of extensions jpeg|jpg|png|doc|docx|pdf|xlsx|mp4|mkv|tff extensions !!!!");
                    return res.status(400).json({ status: "error", message: customError.message });
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
        } catch (error:any) {
            const customError = new Error("Internal Server Error");
            return res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: customError.message });
        }
    },
    s3Controller.uploadFiletoS3
);

Above I my route I have tried creating sperate middleware to get the req.body.type but I am not able to get req.body.type in both before the route and also into the below Image which I my upload function in that to I am not getting the body.file.type only getting the files which I am uploading.

